# PHP Header with random ID variable

Tags: php, mysql, random, header

Facing problem with the following code:

```
<?php   
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
        if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("abc", $con);

        $ids = intval($_GET['id']);
        if ($ids==0){
            $id = rand (0,10);
        }

        header("Location: http://index.php?id=$id");
?>
```

Browsers showing that "This page have too many redirects". Anyone please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Is that code in `index.php`?

Comment: Your header should be that : `header("Location: /index.php?id=$id");`

Comment: Well last line definitely missing URI Host. It should be http://yourhost.com/index.php?id=$id OR just index.php?id=$id as @Broken Heart says.

Answer (score 2):

You always call `header()`, even when `$_GET['id']` is already set to a non-zero value. Thus you have an infinite redirect loop.

If you move the `header()` call inside the `if` block, the infinite loop will go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use If condition with the assigning the value in a variable instead of header

for example:

If($id="something")
{
$error="Ohhh!!!, You are wrong";
$color="bg-color-red";
}

and then call these variable when you are submitting the page.
```